# Cloud Run autoscaling based on CPU utilization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

What CPU utilization percentile does Cloud Run used as condition for autoscaling? Is it P100 over a one minute window?

From the following document, it mentioned CPU utilization being above 60% can be a trigger.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling

> The CPU utilization of existing instances when they are processing requests or events over a one minute window, targeting to keep scheduled instances to a 60% CPU utilization.

During load testing, my Cloud Run instance is getting P99 and P95 CPU utilization above 60% but the P50 is way below 20%. The instance does not seem fully utilized as a result.

The cause for getting P99 and P95 utilization is still unknown but likely due to spikes from garbage collection. Depending on actual percentile used for autoscaling, would have to bring that down.

I've looked at other documentation but nothing seem to mention the exact percentile.
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#choosing-scaling

Comment: In real scenario, we can not predict real scaling model as it may change without any notice. As per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#choosing-scaling) if you have selected **CPU always allocated**, `cloud run` will not auto scale even if CPU usage is over the 60% threshold.

Comment: The document also mentioned "CPU always allocated and perform background activities without requests" and in my case the instance is receiving requests. I assume autoscale will consider CPU usage here?

Comment: Can you confirm, are you using **CPU only allocated during request processing** or **CPU always allocated**?

Comment: when you select [**CPU always allocated**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#choosing-background-execution) it will let you perform background activities when there are no requests recieved

Comment: I am using CPU always allocated.

Comment: I am able to run background activities. The unknown to me is about in what CPU percentile does cloud run based its autoscaling. If say the instance do high cpu work causing 1-sec spike to 100% cpu but after back to 20% cpu to handle requests, will cloud run see that as being stressed and so direct new requests to new instance?

Comment: As I mention **CPU always allocated**, cloud run will not auto scale even if CPU usage is over the 60% threshold. And sometimes auto-scaling may also depends on [maximum concurrency rate](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#maximum_concurrent_requests_per_instance).

Comment: Do you mean that the AND in this sentence below is either condition will not autoscale based on cpu usage?
"If you select CPU always allocated and perform background activities without requests, Cloud Run will not scale out even if CPU usage is over the 60% threshold"

Comment: Thanks btw. So I guess I can not worry about having cpu usage going over 60% as it will be maximized based on concurrency

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have converted my comment into an answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Although, we can’t predict the `cloud run` auto scaling model as it may change without any notice. But, As per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#choosing-scaling) “If you select **CPU always allocated** and perform background activities without requests, Cloud Run will not scale out even if CPU usage is over the 60% threshold.”

In order to better handle (possible) traffic, the autoscaler can sense a spike in traffic and validate the [maximum concurrency rate](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#maximum_concurrent_requests_per_instance) set then overprovision instances.